# How to subtract two date columns(format: 2019-01-31 23:45:45+01:00) in Excel and display in hours?

Tags: excel

Let say I have two columns:

```
Creation Date                Delivery date                 hours
2019-01-31 23:45:45+01:00    2019-02-01 15:18:21+01:00     ?
```

can anyone please help me in doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Their are other ways but this works:

```
=((DATE(LEFT(C3,4),MID(C3,6,2),MID(C3,9,2))-DATE(LEFT(B3,4),MID(B3,6,2),MID(B3,9,2)))-1)+((1-(TIME(MID(B3,12,2),MID(B3,15,2),MID(B3,18,2))))+TIME(MID(C3,12,2),MID(C3,15,2),MID(C3,18,2)))*24
```

in case it is text, c3 is delivery, b3 is creation.

Answer (score 0):

Use `VALUE` and `LEFT` functions:

```
=(VALUE(LEFT(B2,LEN(B2)-6))-VALUE(LEFT(A2,LEN(A2)-6)))
```

and format number in result column with custom format `[h]:mm` or `[h]`

[image]